# array required but "Vector" found en suma de arreglos (Vectores)

Tags: java, array, vectores, required

Me sale error al querer crear el tercer arreglo a partir de otros dos creados previamente.
Exactamente en la línea

```
                       Vector3[i] = Vector1[i]-Vector2[i];
```

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Vector Vector1 = new Vector(7);     
    Vector Vector2 = new Vector(7);     
    Vector Vector3 = new Vector(7);     
               
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number = 0;
    double sum=0, aver=0;
    int i=0;
   
    System.out.println("Favor ingresar 7 números enteros para el Vector 1:");
    
    for(i=0;i<7;i++)
    {        
    System.out.print("Posición "+i+ ": ");
                       number = sc.nextInt();
                       Vector1.add(number); 
                       sum+=number;
    }
    System.out.println("Favor ingresar 7 números enteros para el Vector 2:");
    
    for(i=0;i<7;i++)
    {        
    System.out.print("Posición "+i+ ": ");
                       number = sc.nextInt();
                       Vector2.add(number);
                       sum+=number;                         
    }
     //Crear el tercer arreglo a partir de la diferencia de los dos primeros

    for(i=0;i<7;i++)
    {        
                       Vector3[i] = Vector1[i]-Vector2[i];
                       sum+=number;                         
    }
```

Comment: Para acceder a la posición i de un Vector se usa elementAt no los corchetes.  Vector1[i] NO, Vector1.elementAt(i) SÍ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

creo que no estás usuando el recurso apropiado.

Los vectores no guardan datos primitivos (int, char). En un vector almacenas objetos

En tu caso utilizaría un simple array o arrayList si quieres

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    int[] v1 = new int[7]; 
    int[] v2 = new int[7];
    int[] v3 = new int[7];   
           
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number1 = 0, number2 = 0, number3 = 0;
    double sum1 = 0,sum2 = 0,sum3 = 0, aver=0;
    int i=0;

    System.out.println("Favor ingresar 7 números enteros para el Vector 1:");

    for(i=0;i<7;i++)
    {        
        System.out.print("Posición "+i+ ": ");
                   number1 = sc.nextInt();
                   v1[i] = number1; 
                   sum1 += number1;
    }
    System.out.println("Favor ingresar 7 números enteros para el Vector 2:");

    for(i=0;i<7;i++)
    {        
        System.out.print("Posición "+i+ ": ");
                   number2 = sc.nextInt();
                   v2[i] = number2;
                   sum2 += number2;                         
    }
    //Crear el tercer arreglo a partir de la diferencia de los dos primeros

    for(i=0;i<7;i++)
    {        
                   v3[i] = v1[i] - v2[i];
                   sum3 += number3;                         
    }
    for(i=0;i<7;i++)
    {        
                   System.out.print(v3[i] + ", ");                         
    }
    System.out.println(""); 
    System.out.println("Los valores del primer array suman " + sum1); 
    System.out.println("Los valores del primer array suman " + sum2);
    System.out.println("Los valores del primer array suman " + sum3);
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Soy nuevo en esto. Pero me solicitan realizar las operaciones (insertar elemento, imprimir vector...) a través de métodos declarados en una clase a parte del Main (Vector). Por eso los Vectores 1,2 y 3 son de tipo Vector y no int.

Comment: Entonces tienes que trabajar con los objetos del vextor, como te ha comentado @RubioRic. Mira ésta página, aquí te explican como funcionan los vectores y como se agregan elementos y se accede posteriormente a ellos. [enlace](https://sites.google.com/a/espe.edu.ec/programacion-ii/home/a1-arreglos/declaracion-manipulacion-y-asignacion-de-vectores/la-clase-vector)